# Header Location dont work on live server but works on localhost

Tags: php, header, location

I have this code which relocates a user to index.php if they set the value of a dropdownmenu
on an irrelevant page to set it for please check my code.

```
if(isset($_GET['d'])&&empty($_GET['d'])===false){
        $cur_page=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        $current_page = substr($cur_page,1);
        $possible_page = array('terms.php','contact.php','about.php');

        if(in_array($current_page,$possible_page)){
               header('Location:/index.php?d='.$_GET['d'].'');
       exit();
    }else{
       echo $_GET['d'];
    }
```

It works fine on my localserver but on live server it does not ?

Comment: You need to better explain what "does not work" means. You also need a space in your header, ie: `'Location: /index.php?d='`

Comment: header() does'nt work if the header is already sent. This happens  as soon as something is outputted to the page, even a space or byte order mark before the PHP tags.

Comment: Have you tried just `header('Location: index.php?d='.$_GET['d'])`? (without the slash)

Comment: @adeneo Well that wouldn't explain why it works locally but not live.

Comment: @jtheman it could be because of different server configurations

Comment: @jtheman this is a follow up of your previous comment. Try write a script in your locally. You will find that if header already sent it is still redirecting. I saw that using php 5.3 in wamp server 2.0

Comment: Are you sure the condition even evaluates to true? PHP_SELF will return any folders added or changes in the pathname, which could result in the in_array function returning false.

Comment: what is the possible solutions to make it work? @Sammitch  have tried the it already..

Comment: @Sammitch It does not redirect just exits

Comment: @adeneo Yes I am sure the condition returns true because of the exit();

Comment: Somewhere near the top of your script throw in an `error_reporting(E_ALL);` because you're probably getting an error somewhere, and it's probably a 'headers already sent on line X'.

Comment: @uby how will I do that or what will I configure?

Comment: I got the same problem, and there are no hell you can do about that, unless you review all your code and find where it have the output, it can be a space in some included script.. really difficult to answer your question.

Comment: Tip. If you get bored about this little s*** problem, use java script instead of header() and be happy.

Answer (score 2):

add `ob_start();` at very beginning of the php script. If it include another file then do not use `?>` in the end. Thanks

Comment: That should be an comment, then if he says "no" then you could suggest it as an answer :)

Comment: Thanks Jonast am new to this community will learn to use it slowly :)

Comment: @jonast92 it should not be a comment. It's have the ability to be a answer cause `ob_start()` have a effect on `header`. Who write answer in comment and ask if it works if i will post it as answer?

Comment: So answering this way is encouraged or not?

Comment: It's not. We may first want to ask all our counter questions, get clear idea of the situation and then suggest our solution. Currently your answer isn't technically an answer, its a question whose affirmative answer is not a confirmed solution

Answer (score 0):

I always use this little method and works perfect in all situation.

```
public static function Redirect($sec, $file)
{
    if (!headers_sent())
    {
        header( "refresh: $sec;url=$file" ); 
    }
    elseif (headers_sent())
    {
        echo '<noscript>';
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="'.$sec.';url='.$file.'" />';
        echo '</noscript>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'window.location.href="'.$file.'";';
        echo '</script>';
    }
}
```

In last case it will redirect for sure.